# Does the pro rate rule on taxes for backdoor Roth IRA conversion apply if you have multiple Roth NOT traditional IRAs?

Tags: united-states, taxes, 401k, ira, roth-ira

This is a follow up of the [question here about rolling over traditional IRAs to 401k](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/155201/what-are-the-reasons-to-avoid-rolling-over-ira-into-401k-plans).

The pro rata rule looks at the amounts in all your **traditional IRAs** when you do a backdoor Roth conversion. Does it matter if you have more than 1 **Roth IRA**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't. The pro-rata rule / the IRA aggregation rule only applies to pre-tax IRAs (Rollover, Traditional, SEP, and SIMPLE IRAs). 401ks, other qualified plans, and Roth accounts aren't counted.